# Querying SQL Server to obtain sum total using CTE and joins

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2012-express

I have a below query that I am trying since yesterday with some 33 records of Employee with employeeId on various conditions:

```
With CTE 
(
    select EmployeeId, and other colums with joins and conditions.
)
```

Now I want to join this query to obtain sum of invoices of each employee from below tables, table1 and table2.

`table1` has `employeeid` so as my CTE has `employeeid` I can join it with table1

```
With CTE 
(
     select EmployeeId, and other colums with joins and conditions.
) 
select *, table1.invoiceId 
from CTE 
left join table1 on table1.employeeid = CTE.employeeId
left join table2 on table2.invoiceid = table1.invoiceid 
groupby
```

But my table1 only have invoices and for each such invoice there are amount spend in other table i.e table2. table2 has column "amount" that I need to sum up depending upon invoiceid.

For more clarity I am writing the table structure or output as below.
I am trying like above but they are not showing correct results

Assume CTE has

```
Emplyeeid empName Empaddress empcode
1          john    America    121
2          sandy    America   122
```

Now table1 has

```
InvoiceId EmployeeId  RecordId PAyeeid
1           1            223     202
2           1            222     212
3           1            121     378
4           2            229     987
5           2            345     333
```

table2 has the coulmm amount that we need for each invoice of epmloyee

now table2

```
InvLine     Invoiceid    Amount
1             1            30
2             1            30
3             1            20
4             2            10
5             2            10
6             2            10
```

The output should be as per employe john has two invoices in table1 ie with Id 1 and 2, and for 1 and 2 invoiceds there are amounts that need to be add up

```
Emplyeeid  empName Empaddress empcode  Amount
1           john    America    121      80
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    With CTE 
    (
     select EmployeeId, and other colums with joins and conditions.
    ) 

    With CTE1 
    (
     select EmployeeId,table1.invoiceid  
     from cte 
     left join table1 on table1.employeeid=CTE.employeeId
    ) 

    select sum(amount), cte1.employeeId from CTE1 
    left join table2 on table2.invoiceid = cte1.invoiceid 
    group by cte1.employeeId
```

but you can join the table1 in the first cte itself. There is no need to go for second cte if the first cte is simple one.